# Need help to write a Vertica Query

Tags: sql, vertica

I have to insert data from table `Location` to `Employees`.

Employees table has below column:

```
Emp_name  Salary  Location_nme
```

Location Table has below column:

```
Emp_name, Salary, Loction_nme, Location_cd
```

I need to insert  data into Employees table like below:

1st case:
when data is exists for location_cd=66
then

```
insert into Employees
            Select Emp_name, salary, location_nme from Location where location_cd=66
```

2nd case:
When data is not exists for location_cd=66
then

```
insert into Employees
     Select 'Unknown', -99, 'Not Available'
```

I need to write one single query where both above cases will be satisfied

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky but `union all` and `not exists` might be the simplest method:

```
insert into Employees
   Select Emp_name, salary, location_nme
   from Location
   where location_cd = 66 
   union all
   select 'Unknown', -99, 'Not Available'
   from dual
   where not exists (select 1 from location where location_cd = 66);
```

Answer (score 0):

if those column have null then you could use coalesce()

```
insert into Employees
            Select coalesce(Emp_name,'Unknown'), 
           coalesce(salary,-99), 
          coalesce(location_nme,'Not Available') from Location where location_cd=66
```

Comment: If the data doesn't exist, `coalesce()` isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Or, a bit faster, as it avoids a UNION operator....

```
INSERT INTO employees
SELECT
  CASE location_cd WHEN 66 THEN emp_name     ELSE 'Unknown'       END
, CASE location_cd WHEN 66 THEN salary       ELSE -99             END
, CASE location_cd WHEN 66 THEN location_nme ELSE 'Not Available' END
FROM location;
```